# What specific use case deserves the =:= operator instead of a context bound, and why?

Tags: scala, type-bounds

In the following code (mentioned in another answer, but leads to a separate question), a so-called evidence parameter is used to indicate to the compiler that the A parameter is of type string via a context bound.

```
case class Foo[A](a:A) { // 'A' can be substituted with any type

                      // type constraint ensures type A
  def getStringLength(implicit evidence: A =:= String) = a.length
}
```

But, why not simply define the class **without a type parameter at all?**  I mean, if you parameterize the type being used, then you want a generic class;  otherwise, why not just omit the type parameter as in the following?

```
case class Foo(a: String) {
  def getStringLength(implicit evidence: A) = a.length
}
```

What is an example where the context bound leads to an advantage?

Comment: The School of Scala website is wrong about that, to my knowledge they never went away.

Comment: Btw, the proof http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$@<:<[-From,+To]extendsFrom=>TowithSerializable